# Issue while updating value of Angular Directive's model while updating from watch of form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Am trying to update the binding of an angular directive through a model that gets updated during the $watch of a form's model. Although the value of the model gets updated in the controller scope in the watch of the form, it does not get updated in within the directives rendering. Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

```
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<test-directive  my-string="myString"></test-directive>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl" >
  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType">

</form>

<input type="text" name="input" ng-model="myModel" required />
{{testString}}
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the Angular setup.

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.directive('testDirective', function ($parse) {
    return{
      restrict: 'E',
    scope:{myString:"=myString"},
      link: function(scope,element,attributes){ 
      var test=[];

      },
      template:' Updated::{{myString}}',

    }
});

app.controller('ctrl',['$scope','$timeout',function($scope,$timeout) {

 $scope.myString='12345';


$scope.$watch('myForm', function(myForm,oldvalue) {
  debugger;
    if(myForm) { 


       $scope.myString='new String';




    }
    else {
        console.log('Form is Undefined');
    }  
});

$scope.$watch('myModel',function(newValue,oldValue){
  console.log(newValue);
});


}]);
```

Essentially, I need to have some data in the directive altered when my form is loaded and accessible through the controller.

Comment: Please don't include pictures of your code, just include your code. Stack Overflow has very nice code formatting. Including the relevant details here makes your question more answerable, and more helpful to people having the same problem.

Comment: Hey @SunilD., have updated the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating your controller twice on different DOM elements that are nested.

```
<!-- Creates a new scope -->
<div ng-controller="ctrl">

<!-- Is pointing to the parent scope -->
<test-directive  my-string="myString"></test-directive>

<!-- Creates a a new nested scope -->
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl" >
  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType">

</form>
```

This means the child scope is going to get it's own property `myString`, which is the one being updated when the `$watch` is fired.

Your custom directive however is pointing to the parent property, so the change would not be reflected.

Comment: That duplicate ng-controller on my form element was something that skipped by me when I was working on plunkr. Thanks!!